# Doubt: Do points inside a circle preserve cross ratio

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, circles, projective-geometry

I got a doubt while a  projective Geometry problem.

Given a circle, say $\omega$ and there's a point inside $\omega $ say C. Now lines $BG, DH, EI,FJ$ pass through point $C$ where points $B,G, D,H, E,I,F,J$ lie on $\omega $ .
[image]

Can we say $(F,D;B,E)=(J,H;G,I)$ ?

Comment: Well, note that this is true when $C$ is the center of $\omega$ and prove that there is a projective transformation which maps $\omega$ to the circle $\omega'$ and maps $C$ to the center of $\omega'$. (It's also true when $C$ is outside $\omega$; for this note that the cross-ratios are equal when $C$ is a point at infinity.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to prove that:
$$\frac{FB}{FE}:\frac{DB}{DE}=\frac{JG}{JI}:\frac{HG}{HI}$$ or
$$\frac{FB}{JG}\cdot\frac{DE}{HI}\cdot\frac{JI}{FE}\cdot\frac{HG}{DB}=1$$ or
$$\frac{CB}{JC}\cdot\frac{CE}{HC}\cdot\frac{JC}{CE}\cdot\frac{HC}{CB}=1,$$ which is obvious.

Comment: Oh..sorry , I was editing and by mistakely , it got clicked in the delete section..anyways thanks again :)

Comment: Great solution !